# Getting an event on input()

Tags: python

I want to get an event or at least run a function each time the `input()` function is called. This should happen without wrapping the `input` function in any way.

Is there a way to get an event or some signal that the `input()` function is called without modifying it directly?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I think a [mre] in this case could be considered superfluous, but for some people it might be clearer for them if they saw some example code rather than just an explanation of what's being asked for. Still, just bluntly saying "where's your code?" seems unnecessarily harsh and presumptuous, since you don't explain *why* having code would be helpful, nor does it explain *what kind* of code could help clarify the question. This is obviously a new user and that doesn't seem very welcoming to me.

Comment: Following up on @Random Davis comment. I can code something up however it won't help. In my mind the only ideal solution is that there is some python function that specifically does it or can simulate it without messing with the input() statement. If you would still like me to code something up I can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Python 3.8, one can use an [audit event](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0578/) to get notified on `input` calls. This allows to specify a hook which gets called on *all* events and may filter out the `input` and its prompt.

```py
import sys

def intercept_input(event, *args):
    # the hook is called on all events
    # only react if it is an interesting one
    if event == "builtins.input":
        # the only input argument is the prompt message
        prompt, = args
        print("Querying for input as", repr(prompt))


sys.addaudithook(intercept_input)
input("Hello?")
```

See the [`sys.addaudithook` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.addaudithook) on how audit hooks work, and the [audit event table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/audit_events.html) for the events an audit hook receives.

---

Note that if the intention is to *capture* the input, then wrapping `input` and replacing it in `builtins.input` is both simpler and faster.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I'm looking for! Much appreciated!!!!